# PhpMyID and mobile browsers

Tags: php, openid

I have PhpMyID running on my server. When I use my own provider to log in with any desktop browser, it works just fine.

But when I try to log in with my handheld device which is running Android 2.2, it would not work. What stackexchange sites tell me is 'Message parameter 'openid.mode' has unexpected value 'cancel.cancel', with other sites it just would not work silently. I tried Opera Mini and the default Android browser.

Any chance to fix or work around that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not handheld-specific. I was not able to work around this without changing my browser.

For example, I get this when using a PhpMyID setup and the latest opera web browser on my desktop PC. But if I switch to Chrome or Firefox, it works ok.